# Jquery append text to different text area is not working

Tags: jquery, textarea

i have two textarea. when i click on the  it should append to text area. please look at JSFIDDLE  code.

**when i click  #one , #two only append to first textarea. and #three, #four only for second textarea.** but my code append to both textareas.

```
     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/home/index" method="post">  


          <div class="hashtag">#one</div>
        <div class="hashtag">#two</div>
  <textarea id="text-box"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value ="ok" id="go" />


        <div class="hashtag">#three</div>
        <div class="hashtag">#four</div>
        <textarea id="text-box1"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value ="ok" id="go" />


        </form>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".hashtag").click(function(){
    var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
    var box = $("#text-box");
    var box1 = $("#text-box1");

    box.val(box.val() + txt);
    box1.val(box1.val() + txt);
  });
});
```

my code append text to both textboxes.

```
 [http://jsfiddle.net/Hhptn/483/][1]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, the code on fiddle you have two input boxes what do you want to do ??

Comment: when i click #one and #two it should append only to first texarea.. my code apped to both textaras. like that when i click on #three and #four it should only append only second textarea, not both.

Comment: Now your link is gone.

Comment: Post a complete code example *in your question* please.

Comment: link http://jsfiddle.net/Hhptn/483/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ucan use a data attribute for the hashtags to specify the destination:

```
<div class="hashtag" data-dest="text-box">#one</div>
<div class="hashtag" data-dest="text-box">#two</div>
<div class="hashtag" data-dest="text-box1">#three</div>
<div class="hashtag" data-dest="text-box1">#four</div>
```

and in the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hashtag").click(function(){
        var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
        var dest = '#' + $(this).data('dest');

        $(dest).val($(dest).val() + txt);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hhptn/485/

Comment: Dear Angelo, this method is working fine. you saved my day! thanks sir,

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to both boxes, you can put a condition.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".hashtag").click(function(){
    var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
    var box = $("#text-box");
    var box1 = $("#text-box1");

   if(txt == '#one' || txt == '#two')  
        box.val(box.val() + txt); 

   if(txt == '#three' || txt == '#four')  
      box1.val(box1.val() + txt);
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

try this,  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hhptn/487/)

```
$(".hashtag").click(function(){
    var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
    var box = $("#text-box");
    var box1 = $("#text-box1");
   if(txt == '#one' || txt == '#two')   { box.val(box.val() + txt); } 
   if(txt == '#three' || txt == '#four') { box1.val(box1.val() + txt);} 
});
```